# Firebase rule allowing children to be deleted only one by one

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Consider the following firebase database rules for users. I wonder if there is a way to write a rule that can delete children (friends) one by one, but not all at once?

Here a simple delete operation will not work, because friends needs to either have been empty or have children. However, it can be updated to have any other children whatsoever, meaning all children can be overwritten at once.

```
"user":
{
    "$uid":
    {
        /* user can read all user data */
        ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
        /* allow to add to friends but not delete */
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid && (!data.child('friends').exists() || newData.child('friends').hasChildren())",
        /* other user data also needs to be writable */
        "name": {},
        /* only explicit user data is allowed */
        "$other": { ".validate": false },
        "friends":
        {
            "$friend_uid": { ".validate": "root.child('user').child($friend_uid).exists()" },
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to firebase policy, .write policies are inherited by children, so the solution is .write rules to each child.

```
"user":
{
    "$uid":
    {
        /* user can read all user data */
        ".read": "$uid == auth.uid",
        /* no writing at this level */
        /* ".write": false, */
        /* user data is still writable */
        "name": { ".write":"$uid == auth.uid" },
        /* no longer necessary */
        /*"$other": { ".validate": false },*/
        "friends":
        {
            "$friend_uid": { ".write":"$uid == auth.uid" },
        },
    }
}
```